# Tradeoff of using a Hashed structure instead of List for speed gain

Tags: java, android, data-structures

I am in the process of learning Android development and one thing I have constantly run against is the dilemma of using a `Map` instead of a `List` **if** :

- There exists a *Key* that maps to my model object
- The *Key* is a field of the model object

I am confused because my requirement is of having a ordered data structure only. For instance I had a List as a source of `RecyclerView.Adapter` and since the Adapter asks for the data by index, a `List` is good to go.

But then later, there was a requirement of searching the existing List and adding some new elements accordingly.(Notice that this still doesn't imply that I use a `Map`) Searching the List imposes a cost of O(n) which I wanted to bring down to O(1) and since my structure facilitates having a Key, I thought of having a Map that provides ordering, hashing as well as retrieval by index. I found such data structure in [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ListOrderedMap.html).

The problem is that since it uses a List separately to maintain the ordered indexing of data, memory footprint of this structure would be considerably higher than using for example an `ArrayList` and memory footprint matters on Mobile development but so does the speed.

My question is that,

Would it be worth the tradeoff of using a `ListOrderedMap` to gain some speed but consume more memory, especially while developing on Mobile?

Comment: What is the type of your key? Is it a String or an int or something else?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : The Keys I have are a String, UUID for 2 of my model data objects.

Comment: @pulp_fiction I would go with the ArrayList, I don't want to waste my memory considering. It could be the data of 1000+ items in it for some of the cases.
Also, It also depends on how frequently I will do my search.

Comment: @Arpit : Hmm.. that's understandable in case this is an internal computation that you are doing not having a direct impact on UX but in case this searching leads directly to displaying something to the user, I would worry and therefore the question. If in that case too, it turns that it's not worth it, that would be something to be careful about. However, I am not sure about that tradeoff.

Comment: @pulp_fiction Java provides an ordered map also, TreeMap, which doesn't use an additional list.